# How do I make my array objects follow the curve?

Tags: animation, materials, objects, bezier-curves

For reference, I want to make the following animation:
[image]
[image]

with the objects rotating around the center like a ferris wheel.

I am currently stuck here:
[image]

I want to make the objects stick to each segment of the path and then rotate around it like the one in the above image, I am unable to find a method to do so..
pls help
[image]

Comment: Do you need all the phones to be different colors, as in your reference? (BTW, small point ... it really helps people to answer, if you cut your file  down to isolate the specific problem you're asking about. It just  makes it easier for them to find their way around.)

Comment: Right now, I just want them to rotate around my circle curve so they look like the reference above... @RobinBetts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, your question is pretty vague, because you wrote "I want to make the following animation", but you posted just one picture.

So we don't really know how the animation should look like.

[image]

if you want to make this animation, you have to do this:

1. add an empty, name it controller, with this location + rotation keyframes

[image] on frame 1

2. on frame 49 add these location + rotation keyframes to your controller

[image]

3. on your iphone object, apply scale + rotation

if you press "T" in graph editor and choose linear, you will get this:

[image]

4. change your array modifier to this:

[image]

--- update

in edit mode, select all vertices of your iphone, then press R X 180.

You have to adapt the controller location to your liking.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I am sorry I couldn't find a way to upload the video on the forum... I'll try to add in a link for that...

How do I make the it such that the bottom of the phone is the origin for the rotation, not the top of the phone.

Comment: I've Added the Video

Comment: i updated my answer. Please click on the checkmark left to my answer, if it helped you. thx

Comment: sorry, i will not update my answer to make now the animation as you posted it. please open another question for that. You may open as many questions as you want. But it is a "good manner" here to NOT enhance your question by new tasks. sorry.